# How to subscribe to global events (e.g. keypress) in a component

Tags: angular

Currently I have a suggestion menu component and, when the corresponding event happens, I increment the corresponding variable (`pressedUp`, `pressedDown`, `pressedEnter`) in the parent component using the `suggestion-menu` in its template.

```html
<suggestion-menu             
  [pressedUp]="pressedUp" 
  [pressedDown]="pressedDown" 
  [pressedEnter]="pressedEnter" 
  [query]="someQuery" 
  (onSuggestionClicked)="doSomething($event)">
</suggestion-menu>
```

Then in the suggestion menu component I detect the change with something like that:

```ts
ngOnChanges(inputChanges) {
    if (inputChanges.pressedUp) {
        //do Something
    }

    if (inputChanges.pressDown) {
        //do Something
    }

    if (inputChanges.pressedEnter) {
        //do Something
    }
}
```

Can this be done in a better, less hacky and more event-oriented way?
I would like all the key events that happen in the window to be listened for by the suggestion menu component. Then, if it is something important to it (e.g up, down or enter pressed), it will need to handle it on its own.

Comment: *"in the component"* - the parent or the child? How can the child decide what is supposed to happen? Or do you just want to `emit` all events from the child across one `@Output` to the parent?

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry for not being clear.. I would like all the key events that happen in the window to be listened by the child component (suggestion-menu). if it is something important to it (e.g up, down or enter pressed) it will need to handle it on its own. Please let me know if it is still not clear

Comment: I already did thanks :)

Comment: Not entirely you didn't, your edit merely restored a redundant *"in Angular 2"* to the title (I removed this as **it's in the tags**) and clarified that the component is the suggestion menu. I meant the other parts of your comment. Never mind, if you want a job doing right...

Comment: I know it is in the tags but I thought titles are important for search indexing.. I personally don't look at the tags..most of my questions where explicit about the technology in the title.. all my edits to others' posts have been approved when I added the technology in the title so far. anyway.. As for the   ambiguity I spotted only one place.. the others seemed pretty straightforward as there are only two components involved in the discussion. Thanks for your time editing my post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the `HostListener` decorator for this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/HostListener-interface.html

```js
import {Component, NgModule, HostListener} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  @HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
  onKeyup(event: any) {
    console.log('keyup..', event);
  }

  @HostListener('window:keyup.enter', ['$event', 'undefined'])
  @HostListener('window:click', ['undefined', '$event'])
  onEnterOrClick(enterEvent, mouseEvent) {
    if (enterEvent) {
      console.log('enter..');
    }
    if (mouseEvent) {
      console.log('click..');
    }
  }

  @HostListener('window:keyup.arrowUp')
  onarrowUp() {
    console.log('arrowUp..');
  }

  @HostListener('window:keyup.arrowDown')
  onarrowDown() {
    console.log('arrowDown..');
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/gx49kaDYFvBVlHo18bru?p=preview

Comment: awesome it worked! Thanks :) Is there a way to have multiple events in the same ```@HostListener``` ?

Comment: Yw! Sure, you can use multiple decorators for your handler function. See my updated answer.

Comment: That's great to hear :) Thanks!