# How to trigger event using Enter key in angular?

Tags: angular, triggers

Please help with this as I am very new to angular.  So in my html, I have this event binding where it would open up a document when a user clicks using the mouse.

```
<div
    fxFlex="1 1 auto"
    fxLayout="column"
    class="content"
    (click)="openDialog($event)">
```

Besides using (click), how can I also trigger the openDialog event to open using Enter key from the keyboard?  Right now it doesn't do anything when I try to use the enter key.

Comment: Can you show the ts file?

Comment: Added the ts portion where it called the openDialog

Comment: Not the spec ts but the component.ts

Answer (score 2):

Try `(keyup.enter)` or `(keydown.enter)`

```
<div
    fxFlex="1 1 auto"
    fxLayout="column"
    class="content"
    (click)="openDialog($event)"
    (keyup.enter)="openDialog($event)"
>
```

Keep in mind that $event is now the keyboard event and not the click event.

Comment: It doesn't work.  The mouse (click) works but using enter keyboard doesn't do anything.  Can I have both click and keyboard events?

Comment: I think you can but try removing the click event and only having the enter event.

Comment: I tried to remove (click) and only use (keyup.enter) but that doesn't do anything either.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50129245/angular-5-button-submit-on-enter-key-press It seems to be working there, I am not sure why it's not working for you. Maybe you have to give it to a button or an input element but I see somebody doing it for a div element.

Comment: I think I found out the issue.  I have the focus on the wrong <div> hence it didn't trigger the event.  By moving the focus to the right div where event is trigger, I was able to use (keyup.enter).  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) decorator on the method in your `*.ts` file without changing the template.

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-trigger-function-on-enter?file=src/main.ts) for example.

Just be sure in your case, to check that the dialog you want to open was not opened already.

```
export class App {
  enterCounter = 0;
  tCounter = 0;

  @HostListener('document:keydown.enter')
  onDocumentKeydownEnter() {
    this.enterCounter++;
  }

  @HostListener('document:keyup.t')
  onDocumentKeyupT() {
    this.tCounter++;
  }
}
```